# Copying Work Items to Azure Devops Cloud (v7) from on premises (v6) for Bugs has error "TF401320: Rule Error for field Resolved Reason"

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm writing a script to copy our work items to the cloud version of Azure Devops. I'm getting an error for bugs only (other types are working). I've tried hacking the source reason in the fields "System.Reason" and "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason" to match the fields in the cloud version but I'm still getting the same error:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "customProperties": {
        "FieldReferenceName": null,
        "FieldStatusFlags": "none",
        "ErrorMessage": "TF401320: Rule Error for field Resolved Reason. Error code: HasValues, LimitedToValues, InvalidNotEmpty.",
        "FieldStatusCode": 0,
        "RuleValidationErrors": [
            {
                "fieldReferenceName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason",
                "fieldStatusFlags": "hasValues, limitedToValues, invalidNotEmpty",
                "errorMessage": "TF401320: Rule Error for field Resolved Reason. Error code: HasValues, LimitedToValues, InvalidNotEmpty.",
                "fieldStatusCode": 1048588,
                "ruleValidationErrors": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF401320: Rule Error for field Resolved Reason. Error code: HasValues, LimitedToValues, InvalidNotEmpty.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.RuleValidationException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",
    "typeKey": "RuleValidationException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3200
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that [this tool](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools) exists?

Comment: Mmmm. I certainly didn't waste two weeks writing my own scripts instead of using this tool.